# At what point does a [Swift] UIView resize it's subviews after being added to a superview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect

I have a Universal screen-sized app in Swift 3.0 with a [dynamically created] `UIView`, which contains a `UILabel` that I need to position based upon the frames of various subviews within said `UIView`. In order to position it correctly, I need the frames of the other subviews to have adjusted to the device screensize first. To achieve this I have tried:

1. finding some clue in the official documentation; but failing to, and thus
2. overriding `layoutSubviews()`, calling `super.layoutSubviews()`; and
3. doing the same with `didMoveToSuperview()`.

All with no success. After both `super.layoutSubviews()` and  `super.didMoveToSuperview()` subview frames have still not been resized to the device screensize.

What do I need to do, please? Thanks in advance.

MJB

Comment: how do you fail with layoutSubviews()? any code? it is working just fine

Comment: Thanks @Lu_ your comment at least let's me know I'm overriding the right method, now I'l have to see why layoutSubviews() isn't doing what is expected of it.